# Spring Boot EventListener always on main thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to create an async listener that would execute after my request has been terminated which mean my transaction has been committed. Unfortunately i was not able to make it happen it is always part of the main thread. Which mean my request would never END before the async methods is finishing. It is basically for creating a webhook service that would send an http request when the request going through my system end and the transaction is committed. Does anyone had a similar issue ?

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventListenerAsync {

  @PostPersist
  public void postPersist(final Event event) {
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
        new TransactionSynchronization() {
          @Override
          public void afterCompletion(final int status) {
            if (status == TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED) {

               // call @async public method from another class

            }
          }
        });
  }

  @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
  public void processEventAsynce(final Event event) {

    // call @async public method from another class
    
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: The "@Async" annotation is ignored if the call is from the same class. You have to put your "@Async" method in another class.

Comment: yes the method call is from another class  @pringi

Comment: Do you have "@EnableAsync" ? Can you also post you "@Async" method signature?

Comment: I actually was being misguided by intellij. When you put a break point in your async it will stop your request execution but if you sleep for 10s and put a break point after, the request will actually get terminated.